# How to evaluate the integral of the exponential of tangent squared?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I was stopped during evaluation of other problem by the integral of
$$\int_0^\frac \pi 2 e^{ic\tan^2\theta}d\theta$$ where $c\neq 0$ and $c\in\Re$.
By variable substitution $x=\tan\theta$, it becomes equivalently
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{icx^2}}{1+x^2}dx.$$ Seems not direct to evaluate and turned to complex plane with two poles $z=\pm i$ and the results vanish. But not sure if this is correct?

Comment: Could you show us the calculation that vanishes?

Comment: While Wolfram Alpha can't evaluate this directly, playing around with a few values leads to the conjecture that, in terms of the [Fresnel integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral),$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{icx^2}dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi e^{-ci}}{2}\left(-(1-i)C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2\left|c\right|}{\pi}}\right)-\left(1+i\right)S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2\left|c\right|}{\pi}}\right)+1\right).$$

Comment: What I tried $\pi i\left(\lim_{z\to+i}(z-i)\frac{e^{icz^2}}{(z+i)(z-i)}+\lim_{z\to-i}(z+i)\frac{e^{icz^2}}{(z+i)(z-i)}\right)=\pi ie^{-ic}(\frac{1}{2i}+\frac{1}{-2i})=0$ seems not correct?

Comment: My objective is to show it vanishes as $c\to\infty$.

Comment: I suspect you'll often find vanishing quantities due to including poles you shouldn't until you learn how infinite semicircular contours work, but for this problem they don't help anyway because of the $\Im z\to\pm\infty$ behaviour of $e^{icz^2}$.

Comment: @J.G.. I am surprised to see Fresnel integrals. I probably made some mistakes but using what you wrote, I do not find the results of numerical integration. Could you provide the Mathematica syntax for your expression ? Thanks & cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You shouldn't be surprised to see them, as they can be rewritten in terms of the error function your answer uses. I actually used [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E%283ix%5E2%29%2F%281%2Bx%5E2%29+from+0+to+inf&dataset=).

Comment: @J.G. Amazing !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bit tedious but workable using partial fraction decomposition.

For each integral appear the cosine and sine integrals as well as the $\text{erf}(.)$ function (this looks normal to me).

After simplifications, the result seems to be
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{icx^2}dx}{1+x^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi}{2}   e^{-i c} \left(1+i\, \text{erfi}\left((1+i)
   \sqrt{\frac{c}{2}}\right)\right)$$ which efffectively tends to $0$ when $c \to \infty$.

A few values for $c=10^k$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & \text{result} \\
 0 & 0.6528042545\, + \,0.3617854763 \, i \\
 1 & 0.2063689904\, + \,0.1872057102 \, i \\
 2 & 0.0629742223\, + \,0.0623477998 \, i \\
 3 & 0.0198265299\, + \,0.0198067133 \, i \\
 4 & 0.0062668840\, + \,0.0062662573 \, i \\
 5 & 0.0019816736\, + \,0.0019816537 \, i \\
 6 & 0.0006266574\, + \,0.0006266568 \, i \\
 7 & 0.0001981664\, + \,0.0001981664 \, i \\
 8 & 0.0000626657\, + \,0.0000626657 \, i \\
 9 & 0.0000198166\, + \,0.0000198166 \, i
\end{array}
\right)$$

These results have been checked using numerical integration.

Using Mathematica, the result is confirmed if $\Im(c)>0$

**Edit**

For large values of $c$ the expansion is
$$\frac{1+i}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2c}}\left(1-\frac{i}{2 c}-\frac{3}{4 c^2}+\frac{15 i}{8
   c^3}+\frac{105}{16 c^4}-\frac{945
   i}{32 c^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{c^6}\right)\right)$$ For $c=10$, this would give
$$\frac{666609\,+\,604631\, i}{2560000} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{5}}\approx 0.2064054\,+\, 0.1872149\,i$$